# nodeJS, using http.request losing session

Tags: node.js, http, session, cookies

i'm developing an application using nodeJS, after i have made login in my app, i need to get a http request, but i have a 302 status response and i'm redirect to login.
I think i need to send cookies session information with my http request.. how is this possible?

here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

    var options = {
        //host: "siadmigo.siadmiservice.com",
        host: "localhost",
        path: "/" + model + "/config/",
        port: '1337',
        withCredentials: true,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(body);
            return callback(null, body);
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        return callback(e, null);
    });

    req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) when you start needing features that the built-in http module does not provide (e.g. handling redirects and remembering cookies). You will need to `npm install tough-cookie` in addition to setting `jar: true` as shown below:

```
var request = require('request');

// ...

// _request() will maintain a cookie jar across multiple calls to _request()
var _request = request.defaults({jar: true});
_request('http://localhost:1337/' + model + '/config/' , function(err, res, body) {
  callback(err, body);
});
```

or use a separate cookie jar instead of a separate `request()` with defaults set:

```
var request = require('request');

// ...

var jar = request.jar();
request({
  url: 'http://localhost:1337/' + model + '/config/',
  jar: jar
}, function(err, res, body) {
  callback(err, body);
});
```

The tradeoff with the second solution is that you can pass around the `jar` object to other `request()` instances, no matter what their defaults are. But then you also have to manually specify the `jar` for each `request()` where you want to use those cookies.